# MVC Partial View with AutoRefresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I need to keep a list of logged users STATUSES at the Server level (either "ONLINE" or "OFFLINE").

So I wrote a Partial View to maintain the user current Status (Online, Offline). 
The server stores these values both on the Database and all the current Online users also in a Cached entry so that I can retrieve the list of all current "Online" users from cache.

In order to keep this list uptodate, I now need an asynchronous AutoRefresh call that notifies the server to keep my userID on the ONLINE list. This call should execute every xx seconds and should only execute if the current status is ONLINE.

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I create an AutoRefresh call that fires every XX seconds
2. How can I ensure this call executes only when I'm in ONLINE status

Thanks in advance.

---

This is the Partial View in question.
Where do you suggest I put the code to run the AutoRefresh (MasterPage, Main View, Partial View) ???

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%  
    if (MySite.Security.SiteUser.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["IsLogged"]))
        {
        %>
            <div id="onlineStatus">                
                You are currently ONLINE >>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Take a Break", "GoOffline", "Account")%>
            </div>
        <%
        }
        else
        { 
        %>
            <div id="offlineStatus">
            Ready for business >>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Go Online", "GoOnline", "Account")%>
            </div>
        <%
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: how do users set themselves are online/offline?

Comment: Users click on the link to go Online or Offline. What I need is to be able to tell the server that the user is still Online.

That's where I need the AutoRefresh feature every XX seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of you put me on the right direction and the final "working" answer is:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function {
                         var url = '<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>';
                         $.getJSON(url, null, function() { });}
                    , 10000);
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can setup a function that does it for you

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (I_AM_ONLINE) {
        window.location.reload(true);
        //Or instead of refreshing the page you could make an ajax 
        //call and determing if a newer page exists.  IF one does then reload.
    }
}, 300000);
```

where 300.000 is the number of milliseconds between each call (5 minutes).

I_AM_ONLINE remain the hardest part and depends on many things....

**EDIT**:

I would add this code inside the partial itself, (preferably at the end of it):

```
<%  if (MySite.Security.SiteUser.IsAuthenticated) {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["IsLogged"])) { %>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval( window.location.reload(true), 300000);
            </script>
<%
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: Where would you put this call on the above PartialView ?

Comment: e grazie per l'aiuto ...Filippo :--)

Comment: I did that and ...the page keeps reloading itself immediately and never completes it's first load.

Comment: That's because the first setInterval event would fire immediately. Can you please better explain your requirement? I'll try to slightly change my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

here's some js with an ajax call and recursive function calls (asynchronous)

```
var onlineupdate;
(onlineupdate = function()
{
   if(online())
   {
     $.post('serverside url', data, function(){
        setTimeout(onlineupdate,XX);
     });
   }
   else
   {
       setTimeout(onlineupdate,XX);
   }
})()
```

again the function for determining what counts as online needs to be determined.

Comment: please note that `setTimeout` will only run once while `setInterval` will run continously...

Comment: with the recursive call it will run continuously, and will still function correctly even if you set XX down to 1, it will still wait for the server to respond before repeating.

Comment: If this a recursive call...is there a MAX number of recursive iterations that can happened ??

Comment: Where would you place this call ...looking at the Partial View code I just added on my initial question ?